# tensorflow-gpu missing libraries dlerror - Import error

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to use Tensorflow-gpu for the first time on HPC cluster. I have some main errors in terms of the lack of libraries that don't let me use the GPU.

```
2020-11-22 14:19:26.629817: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_lo                                                                                                                                                                             ader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.10.1'; dlerror: libcuda                                                                                                                                                                             rt.so.10.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRAR                                                                                                                                                                             Y_PATH: /opt/R/3.5.1/lib64/R/lib:/opt/cluster/lib:/opt/cluster/external/p7zip-16                                                                                                                                                                             .02/lib/p7zip
2020-11-22 14:19:26.629870: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29]                                                                                                                                                                              Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2020-11-22 14:19:30.479705: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2020-11-22 14:19:31.048853: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:82:00.0 name: Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB computeCapability: 6.0
coreClock: 1.3285GHz coreCount: 56 deviceMemorySize: 15.90GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 681.88GiB/s
2020-11-22 14:19:31.049038: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.10.1'; dlerror: libcudart.so.10.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/R/3.5.1/lib64/R/lib:/opt/cluster/lib:/opt/cluster/external/p7zip-16.02/lib/p7zip
2020-11-22 14:19:31.049540: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'libcublas.so.10'; dlerror: libcublas.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/R/3.5.1/lib64/R/lib:/opt/cluster/lib:/opt/cluster/external/p7zip-16.02/lib/p7zip
2020-11-22 14:19:31.049988: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'libcufft.so.10'; dlerror: libcufft.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/R/3.5.1/lib64/R/lib:/opt/cluster/lib:/opt/cluster/external/p7zip-16.02/lib/p7zip
2020-11-22 14:19:31.050412: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'libcurand.so.10'; dlerror: libcurand.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/R/3.5.1/lib64/R/lib:/opt/cluster/lib:/opt/cluster/external/p7zip-16.02/lib/p7zip
2020-11-22 14:19:31.050833: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'libcusolver.so.10'; dlerror: libcusolver.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/R/3.5.1/lib64/R/lib:/opt/cluster/lib:/opt/cluster/external/p7zip-16.02/lib/p7zip
2020-11-22 14:19:31.051262: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'libcusparse.so.10'; dlerror: libcusparse.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/R/3.5.1/lib64/R/lib:/opt/cluster/lib:/opt/cluster/external/p7zip-16.02/lib/p7zip
2020-11-22 14:19:31.539912: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-11-22 14:19:31.539974: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1753] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
Num GPUs Available:  0
```

By using "nvcc -version" I have:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2018 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sat_Aug_25_21:08:01_CDT_2018
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.0, V10.0.130
```

cudatoolkit version: 9.0 and cudnn: 7.6.5, tf: 2.3.1

I looked up online and found some similar errors, but, solutions did not work in my case. can you please help me?

Comment: your tensorflow appears to be looking for CUDA 10.1 `libcudart.so.10.1: cannot open shared object file:`.  You **cannot** use CUDA 10.0, or CUDA 9.0, or any other version of CUDA to satisfy that requirement.

Comment: Just cant load CUDA 10.1 cause you havent install CUDA 10.1 U have installed CUDA 10.0

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Robert Crovella and As per the [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu) website, Tensorflow 2.3.1 version requires CUDA 10.1.

And, Error also says `Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.10.1'`.